# Shell script - copy lines from file by key

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have two input files such that:

```
file1
123
456
789

file2
123|foo
456|bar
999|baz
```

I need to copy the lines from file2 whose keys are in file1, so the end result is:

```
file3
123|foo
456|bar
```

Right now, I'm using a shell script that loops through they key file and uses grep for each one:

```
grep "^${keys[$keyindex]}|" $datafile >&4
```

But as you can imagine, this is extremely slow.  The key file (file1) has approximately 400,000 keys and the data file (file2) has about 750,000 rows.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are you using a shell script?

Comment: The are many other steps that happen prior to this point in a larger script. I was hoping to not need to maintain two different things.

Comment: I've never tried it, but I think you could embed the python code in a multi-line bash string and send it to the python interpreter directly without having a separate file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join):

```
join -t'|' file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like Python, which would process it pretty fast if you used an optimized data type like `set`.  Not sure of your exact requirements, so you would need to adjust accordingly.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Create a set to store all of the items in file1
Set1 = set()
for line in open('file1', 'r'):
   Set1.add(line.strip())

# Open a file to write to
file4 = open('file4', 'w')

# Loop over file2, and only write out the items found in Set1
for line in open('file2', 'r'):
   if '|' not in line: 
      continue

   parts = line.strip().split('|', 1)
   if parts[0] in Set1:
       file4.write(parts[1] + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

`join` is the best solution, if sorting is OK. An awk solution:

```
awk -F \| '
    FILENAME==ARGV[1] {key[$1];next} 
    $1 in key
' file1 file2
```